# Create Matrix from tdbc::odbc $resultset allrows -as lists

Tags: matrix, odbc, tcl, tdbc

I have a result set that I am returning from a result set. I am wanting to turn that into a matrix object to perform in memory lookups on the data. I have never used Matrix and am stuck on getting it to work. Can anyone provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, the trip through CSV can be avoided by using the matrix's `add row` method directly.

```
::struct::matrix Mtrx
Mtrx add columns [llength [$SQLResultSet columns]]
while {[$SQLResultSet nextlist Return_Row]} {
    Mtrx add row $Return_Row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
::struct::matrix Mtrx
Mtrx add columns [llength [$SQLResultSet columns]]
while {[$SQLResultSet nextlist Return_Row]} {
    ::csv::split2matrix Mtrx [::csv::join $Return_Row] {,} {expand auto}
}
```

From here you can do what you need.

Comment: The round trip via CSV seems… excessive to me.

Comment: @DonalFellows - I was hopping that you would respond. There isn't a whole lot of examples for the Matrix package. How would one go about doing it direct from a list of lists? Say if I were to use allrows from ODBC.